# UWP: Get the reference of control's bound object programmatically

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, xaml, uwp

How do I get a reference to a object bound to a control displayed as part of ItemsRepeater?

XAML:

```
<Grid>
        <controls:ItemsRepeater ItemsSource="{x:Bind cars}">
            <controls:ItemsRepeater.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:Car">
                    <Button Content="{x:Bind Brand}" Tapped="Button_Tapped"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </controls:ItemsRepeater.ItemTemplate>
        </controls:ItemsRepeater>
</Grid>
```

C#:

```
private ObservableCollection<Car> cars = new ObservableCollection<Car>()
{
            new Car()
            {
                Brand = "Audi",
                Model = "123",
                Color = "Red",
                Price = "100 000 $"
            },
            new Car()
            {
                Brand = "BMW",
                Model = "456",
                Color = "Black",
                Price = "150 000 $"
            },
};

private void Button_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
   // Warning: The code line bellow does not work. The problem is here.
   Car selectedCar = (sender as FrameworkElement).DataContext as Car;

   Debug.WriteLine("Brand: " + selectedCar.Brand);
   Debug.WriteLine("Model: " + selectedCar.Model);
   Debug.WriteLine("Color: " + selectedCar.Color);
   Debug.WriteLine("Price: " + selectedCar.Price);

   // Expected result (if Audi button is tapped):
   // Brand: Audi
   // Model: 123
   // Color: Red
   // Price: 100 000 $

   // Actual result: 
   // System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

}
```

EDIT: Updated the example code to be better illustrate the issue.

> It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Updated due to update of the original question.

While trying my previously used method for this I found an even easier solution which should enable you to just use your original code.

#### 1. The simple solution

Just add

```xml
DataContext="{x:Bind}"
```

to your

```xml
<Button Content="{x:Bind Brand}" Tapped="Button_Tapped"/>
```

line.

#### 2. My original solution

This solution is similar to above stated solution, however for this I introduce an extra `DependencyProperty` to a custom `Button` class:

```cs
public class CustomButton : Button
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty BoundCarProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("BoundCar", typeof(Car), typeof(CustomButton), new PropertyMetadata(new Car(), new PropertyChangedCallback(BoundCarValueChanged)));
    private static void BoundCarValueChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        SpecialButton s = d as SpecialButton;
        Car c = d.GetValue(BoundCarProperty) as Car;
    }

    public Car BoundCar
    {
        get => (Car)GetValue(BoundCarProperty);
        set => SetValue(BoundCarProperty, value);
    }
}
```

Now I change the XAML to:

```xml
<local:SpecialButton BoundCar="{x:Bind Mode=OneWay}" Content="{x:Bind Brand}" Tapped="Button_Tapped"/>
```

As an added benefit to the first solution, this enables you to catch changes to the bound property, which you can handle in the `BoundCarValueChanged` event.

Comment: Ahh. Dumb mistake while trying to create a simple looking example. I obviously know that int cannot be directly casted to string. In my real scenario, I have an ObservableCollection of complex objects bound to a ItemsRepeater via DataTemplate. That's why I can't simply retrieve value form the property, since I don't know which element of the collection the tapped control is.

Comment: @Vinderguy In that case it may be better if you updated your question to be more specific to your situation. I will then remove this answer and try to answer for your situation. Other people will then be more able to also provide a more specific answer, if I'm not able to.

Comment: Thank you for your willingness to help. I've updated my question to better describe my problem.

Comment: Thanks so much! The first solution you provided is exactly what I've been looking for. Just one XAML line and the issue is fixed. Before, I was also thinking about creating custom button control, and the second solution nicely explains how it can be achieved. One more time, great job! Have a good day.